# oracle form hidden field from the display item

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, hidden-field

I am trying show or hidden the Minus sign from the extended price(display item)

table

```
Transaction Portfolio_Number    PK  Number (7,0)        FK  Not Null
    Stock_Code      Varchar2 (10)       FK  Not Null
    Transaction_Date        Date    Not Null
    Exchange_Code       Varchar2 (4)        FK  Not Null
    Broker_Number       Number (7,0)        FK  Not Null
    Buy_Sell        Char (1)    Not Null
    Quantity        Number (7,0)    Not Null
    Price_Per_Share     Number (6,2)    Not Null
```

my display item is quantity * price_per_share.

if it is buy then the extended price will have the minus sign .
if  it is sell then the extended price will be have the minus sign(which hidden the field?) 
one thing is the minus sign mean it is negative. because i will using it to calculation the extended price total. 
if you have another way work. also share with me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what you are saying; example would certainly help.

Meanwhile: you said that:

- if buy_sell = buy then price_per_share is negative
- if buy_sell = sell then ... what? I have no idea what sentence you wrote means:

  > then the extended price will be have the minus sign(which hidden the field?)

  That looks the same as "buy" to me.

Also, what is "extended price total"?

As I said: example and - possibly - rephrasing the question would help.

---

Meanwhile, see if this helps:

```
:block.display_item := case when :block.buy_sell = 'B' then -1
                            when :block.buy_seel = 'B' then  1
                       end * :block.quantity * abs(:block.price_per_share);
```

which says: never mind what `price_per_share`'s sign is (positive or negative) - always take its absolute value (that's what `abs` function does). Multiply it by `quantity`. Decide which sign to use by checking `buy_sell` value (I presumed that buy means *negative*, while sell means *positive*).

---

If there are two tables involved, join them and select into a block item (presuming that above code makes sense); something like this:

```
select sum(case when t.buy_sell = 'B' then -1
                when t.buy_sell = 'S' then  1
           end * t.quantity * abs(t.price_per_share)
          )
into :block.display_item
from transaction t join portfolio p on p.portfolio_number = t.portfolio_number
where t.portfolio_number = :block.portfolio_number;
```

Comment: what is the syntax if table is not from the transaction, The table Portfolio,it has protfolio_number as PK which is transaction's FK. and sum them all.

Comment: I edited my answer and added some more code; have a look, please.

Comment: Why did you mention another table, then?